# How to On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: python, mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key

I have this query that is executed in my Python script but when its inserting into the database and finds a duplicate of my unique column it causes it to error and stops. I know I need to use On Duplicate Key Update but I'm note sure how to properly add this.

My unique column 2.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO logs (1,2,3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s) """,(line[0], line[1], line[2]))
```

If there is a duplicate to have it update that row/entry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is this:

```
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO logs (1, 2, 3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 1=%s, 3=%s """, (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[0], line[2]))
```

Check also [Insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Yes, and I've tried a couple of times to implement that in the code above but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: So what is not working out? What is happening when you execute this line?

Comment: cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO logs (1, 2, 3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 1=%s, 3=%s """, line[0], line[1], line[2], line[0], line[2])
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)

Comment: That's because I forgot the parantheses around the parameters. I fixed it above, please try again.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the assistance! It is working now and updating the rows without throwing errors or stopping the rest of the script.

So "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 1=%s, 3=%s" you are referring back to the Insert statement where the columns are the numbers. Then for each %s there has to be a parameter(the line[#] part) to go with the 5 %s in the statement?

Comment: Exactly. The `%s` are placeholders that have to be filled later on, and you have to assign the same values as in your insert to the according column to get the functionality you want. By the way, the column names don't seem to be optimal since they are not describing what is stored in them.