# Python "INSERT INTO" vs. "INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use python to insert a record into a MySQL database and then update that record.  To do this I have created 2 functions:

**def insert_into_database():**

```
query = "INSERT INTO pcf_dev_D.users(user_guid,username) VALUES (%s, %s) "
data = [('1234', 'user1234')]
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('db/db_config.ini')
db = {}
section = 'mysql'

if parser.has_section(section):
    items = parser.items(section)
    for item in items:
        db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
    raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

try:
    conn = MySQLConnection(**db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    conn.commit()
except Error as e:
    print('Error:', e)
finally:
    # print("done...")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

This works fine and inserts 1234, user1234 into the db.

Now I want to update this particular user's username to '5678', so I have created another function:

**def upsert_into_database():**

```
query = "INSERT INTO pcf_dev_D.users(user_guid,username) " \
        "VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='%s'"
data = [('1234', 'user1234', 'user5678')]
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('db/db_config.ini')
db = {}
section = 'mysql'

if parser.has_section(section):
    items = parser.items(section)
    for item in items:
        db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
    raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, 'db/db_config.ini'))

try:
    conn = MySQLConnection(**db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    conn.commit()
except Error as e:
    print('Error:', e)
finally:
    # print("done...")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Which produces the following error:
Error: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

What's interesting is if I modify query and data to be:

```
query = "INSERT INTO pcf_dev_D.users(user_guid,username) " \
        "VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username='user5678'"
data = [('1234', 'user1234')]
```

Then python updates the record just fine...what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You included the 3rd parameter within single quotes in the `update` clause, therefore it is interpreted as part of a string, not as a placeholder for parameter. You must not enclose a parameter by quotes:

```
query = "INSERT INTO pcf_dev_D.users(user_guid,username) " \
        "VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=%s"
```

UPDATE

If you want to use the `on duplicate key update` clause with a bulk insert (e.g. `executemany()`), then you should not provide any parameters in the `update` clause because you can only have one update clause in the bulk insert statement. Use the [values()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) function instead:

```
query = "INSERT INTO pcf_dev_D.users(user_guid,username) " \
        "VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username)"
```

> In assignment value expressions in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES() function is meaningful only in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause or INSERT statements and returns NULL otherwise.

Comment: This would mean `data` would also need to be modified, right?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no because it has 3 parameters already (hence the error message)

Comment: @nollie11 I have tried it (different table, obviously) and for me it works without the quotes.

Comment: Ugh, I believe you @Shadow - can you share the exact lines of query and data?

Comment: @nollie11 The table name was simply test, otherwise everything else was the same. Also, see the following very similar SO question and its answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322880/how-to-on-duplicate-key-update The code in the accepted answer also does not include the placeholders within quotes.

Comment: @Shadow, I think I found out why my code is not working and yours is.  Is yours using cursor.execute() or cursor.executemany()?  If cursor.execute, I can get that to work no problem.  My original question (and I should have been more clear) is around performing an insert on duplicate key update when I have a large set of data, rather then iterating through each record and executing an upsert for each one.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @nollie11 yep, that's an important difference, see the updated answer.