# Add dataframe column WITH VARYING VALUES to MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Pretty simple question, but not sure if it’s possible from what I’ve seen so far online.

To keep it simple, let’s say I have a MySQL table with 1 column and 5 rows made already. If I have a pandas dataframe with 1 column and 5 rows, how can I add that dataframe column (with its values) to the database table?

The [guides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inserting-data-into-a-new-column-of-an-already-existing-table-in-mysql-using-python/amp/) I’ve read so far only show you how to simply create a new column with either null values or 1 constant value, which doesn’t help much. The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604929/how-to-append-new-column-to-mysql-with-pandas) but the answer provided didn’t answer the question, so I’m asking it again here.

As an example:

MySQL table:
[image: mysqltable]

Pandas DataFrame:
[image: pandasdataframe]

Desired MySQL table:
[image: desired]

Then for kicks, let's say we have a string column to add as well:
[image: dataframe2]

Desired MySQL output:
[image: newDesired]

Safe to assume the index column will always match in the DF and the MySQL table.

Comment: You want to insert the values in the existing column ? Why just not insert the values ? Are the data type the same ? Can you edit the question and add a practical example

Comment: @ErgestBasha Done, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

You have the following table:

```
create table tbl (
index_ int ,
col_1 int ,
primary key index_(`index_`)
) ;

insert into tbl values  (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5);
```

And want to add the following data in a new column on the same table ;

```
(1,0.1),(2,0.2),(3,0.3),(4,0.4),(5,0.5)
```

First you need to add the column with the alter command,

```
alter table tbl add column col_2 decimal(5,2) ;
```

Then use  INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl (index_,col_2)
VALUES 
(1,0.1),
(2,0.2),
(3,0.3),
(4,0.4),
(5,0.5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_2=VALUES(col_2);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ff6bfd7cef0783888004881488fcc2c)

Comment: I think the core problem is OP does not know how to ALTER table add columns in pandas - neither do I, do you know of a way?

Comment: @ErgestBasha well, I should reiterate, it’s CLOSE. The query will work, but how can I iterate through the pandas column to insert the values into the table? These columns I made are small, but we have to assume the size of the columns is too large to manually define like this

Comment: @MattWilson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255460/python-insert-into-vs-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update